# Не работает javascript фнукция

Tags: javascript, html

Есть переменная, которая должна получить значение true, если на странице есть определенный класс.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Igw0E">
        
    </div>
    <script>
         let virustotal = false;
    let fruits = ["Igw0E", "IwRSH", "bkEs3", "MMzan"];
    fruits.map(async x => {
        if (!document.getElementByclass(x)) return;
        if (document.getElementByclass(x)) virustotal = true;
    });
    console.log(virustotal)



    document.querySelector('body').classList.add('body_del');
    document.querySelector('head').classList.add('head_app');
    let body = document.getElementsByClassName('body_del');
    let head = document.getElementsByClassName('head_app');

    if (virustotal) {
        body[0].innerHTML = '<div class="block"><div class="text"><div class="caption"><p class="head">сайт заблокирован</p></div><div class="definition"><p class="fhish">Этот сайт является средством фишинга</p><p>Пожалуйста покиньте сайт</p><p><a href="https://rb.ru/story/what-is-fishing/">дополнительная информация о фишинге</a></p></div></div></div>';
        head[0].innerHTML += '<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"> <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin> <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Play:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"><style>* {margin: 0;padding: 0;font-weight: 400;font-size: 50px;color: white;font-family: "play";}body {background-color: #25253D;}p{text-align: center;}.head {color: #DD3232;font-weight: 700;text-transform: uppercase;font-size: 76px;padding-bottom: 25px;}.block {display: flex;flex-direction: column;justify-content: center;align-items: center;height: 100vh;}.definition > p > a {font-size: 24px;text-align: center;transition: all 1s;}.definition > p > a:hover {font-size: 24px;text-align: center;color: #DD3232;}</style>';
    } else {

    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Переменная virustotal не меняет свое значение

проблема, видимо с участком

```
let virustotal = false;
let fruits = ["Igw0E", "IwRSH", "bkEs3", "MMzan"];
fruits.map(async x => {
    if (!document.getElementByclass(x)) return;
    if (document.getElementByclass(x)) virustotal = true;
});
console.log(virustotal)
```

Comment: произведите отладку кода.

Comment: и зачем тут map?  и что такое `getElementByclass` и откуда вы это взяли?